# what is the complexity of int multiplyRec(int m, int n){ if(n == 1) return m; return m + multiplyRec(m, n - 1); }

Tags: time-complexity

What is the time complexity of the following recursive relation? and how?

```
int multiplyRec(int m, int n){
if(n == 1)
    return m;
return m + multiplyRec(m,  n - 1);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's O(n), but not if the function is called with n < 1 - in that case you'll get stack overflow error

Answer (score 0):

If each function call of recursive algorithm takes O(m) space and if the maximum depth of recursion tree is 'n' then space complexity of recursive algorithm would be O(nm).

Answer (score 0):

It is O(n) because here we are calculating T(n) = K + T(n-1) and so on here k is constant.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here =`o(n) because T(n)=k1+k2+T(n-1) :k1+k2=K so we have T(n)=K+T(n-1)
and by method of substitution method we get T(n)=k(n+1)
T(n)= k*n because ignore term k so time complexity is o(n)

Answer (score 0):

O(n)
recurence relation is  T(n)= K+ T(n-1)
here k is constant term
and  we search in the linear manner.

Answer (score 0):

It is O(n) because here we are calculating T(n) = K + T(n-1) and so on here k is constant.

where K is equal to m and its just taking extra space instead u can use for loop to improve it

but its taking O(N) why?

example n=5,m=1;

```
1.r(5)
   1+r(4)
2.r(4)
   1+r(3)
3.r(3)
   1+r(2)
4.r(2)
   1+r(1)
5.completing r(1) 
   returning 1
6.completing r(2) 
   1+1 = 2, returning 2
7.completing r(3)
   1+2 = 3, returning 3
8.completing r(4)
   1+3 = 4, returning 4
9.completing r(5)
   1+4 = 5
```

hence 5 is the answer and here u might thought that there are 9 steps but I still am saying it's gonna take O(n) time
that is because it takes time in calling the function and we do not count returning time